# ASP Web Forms Removing Class Client-Side from ViewState

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to determine the proper way to remove a class from an element client-side and maintaining that removal in the ViewState. For example, I have a form with a Custom Validator. The custom validator will determine one or more fields have invalid input. It will then add a css class to the element so that it will appear red:

```
TextBox_UserName.CssClass += " error";
```

On the client-side I have an onkeyup function that will remove the class so that when the user starts typing in the field it goes back to the default style:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UserName" runat="server" onkeyup="clearError(event, this)" />
```

The Javascript function is pretty simple:

```
function clearError(event, elem) {
    if (event.keyCode != 9 && event.keyCode != 16 && event.keyCode != 13)
        $(elem).removeClass('error');
}
```

This works well but the problem I'm running into is this; say the user enters a value which clears the error class, then they change the value of another control on the form which causes a post back, when the form reloads after post back, the error class is back on the TextBox_UserName control. I'm assuming this is happening because the class is added via code-behind thus becomes saved in the ViewState.

Is there a way I can remove or update an element's class client-side and have that change reflected in the ViewState?

The only thing I can think of is adding logic to the code-behind to handle this but the form I'm working with has a large number of fields so this is not ideal. The other option I suppose would be to use a telerik AjaxManager so that only the fields that cause post backs are affected by the post back but this isn't really ideal either. I'm hoping there is a better or more efficient way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish using javascript. I haven't had luck finding a solution because everything I find talks about how changing the ViewState will cause errors (and I don't want to remove this either).

EDIT: I opted for this solution:

In my custom validator method I clear the error class from all the controls that may be affected. I then check if each field is valid and then add the error class to the fields that fail my checks. Then I update the value of a hidden field to indicate that validation has occurred on the form.

In the methods that handle the events of the controls that trigger post backs, I check if validation has occurred and if it has, I make a call to:

```
Page.Validate();
```

This will trigger my custom validator again and since it will clear the error classes first, it updates the css class for the fields that haven't been fixed by the user while leaving the fixed fields alone.

Comment: Take a step back and rethink what you are doing. You are using Validators but you are interfering with their workflow. Maybe there is a way to use them 'properly', hence not having to write extra code to keep things working.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not sure what you mean though. I'm just trying to style the elements that fail validation while allowing the user to fix the problem and in turn, clearing the style that indicates there is a problem, while maintaining that in the ViewState so future post backs don't cause the error style to come back. Can you please elaborate on how I'm interfering with the validator's workflow so I can have a better understanding that will allow me to come up with a better solution? I've edited my question to explain how I've solved it but maybe it's not the best approach.

Comment: That's what I mean. The Validators are supposed to take care of the styling. When you start to "interfere", you are leaving the intended way they work. Usually, to be safe, I would write code behind _and_ client side validation for a Custom Validator. You should be fine then.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can't change the view state on the client side.  How about putting all the controls that cause a post back into an update panel?  That way only those controls are affected during a post back.  Personally I prefer to use the AJAX function in jQuery for partial post backs because it's much more light weight.  But since you're using Web Forms, an update panel would be a quick solution if you're not familiar with jQuery AJAX.

Another option would be to save the state of the textbox in a hidden field.  Then the server code would know what class to apply to the textbox.

Comment: These are good solutions. I wanted to avoid wrapping individual controls in UpdatePanels/AjaxPanels (the project I'm working in utilizes Telerik controls). The main reason for this is because the entire form is already wrapped in an AjaxPanel so I don't want to break it up. I opted to use a hidden field but in a different way than your suggestion as I think it will require less changes. I've edited my question to explain what I've done.